# FFMPEG - Merge two MP4 files

Tags: video, ffmpeg

To merge two MP4 file, it's necessary to pass by .ts file.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts input1.ts
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts input2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.ts|input2.ts" -c copy output.mp4
```

But, I have this error on first/second command:

> Codec 'mpeg4' (13) is not supported by the bitstream filter
>   'h264_mp4toannexb'. Supported codecs are: h264 (28) Error initializing
>   bitstream filter: h264_mp4toannexb

[image]

Have you got an idea?

Comment: The videostream ist not H.264 (MPEG 4 AVC) bit H.263 (MPEG4 ASP aka xvid/divx)

Comment: you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17487021/3082472)

Comment: I can't, the problem is for first/second commands...

Comment: I'll tried this sorry, I have result: VLC open file but the time of the video is duplicated, I can't advance in time, and the second file isn't visible/audible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do it using the `concat` protocol which concatenates at the file level.

Do you get better results if you try to concatenate via the demuxer?

You would list your input files in a text file (mylist.txt) and then:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

The `-safe 0` is not required if the paths are relative.

This method and the one you tried are both suggested [here on ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) as well as various other methods of concatenation. Surely there is one there that will work for you? If all else fails you could transcode them to h264 first, which apparently they are not already in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem

> Stream #0:0[0x1]: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D),

as stated by @stoney, it needs to be

> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661)

You can verify this by first recoding to h264.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 output1.mp4
ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts input1.ts
```